# Force pdf download with <a> tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to force a pdf download with the  tag.

Here is what I have:

```
 <a ID="personal_training_form" class="pdfcalltoaction" OnServerClick="personal_training_form_Click" runat="server">PERSONAL TRAINING FORM</a>
```

and my codebehind:

```
public void personal_training_form_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=PersonalTrainingForm.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile("~/programs/PERSONAL_TRAINING_FORM_to_mail.pdf");
    Response.End();
}
```

It appears that the page is just refreshing, no file is being downloaded.

EDIT:

So i've tried switching it to a LinkButton, but it is still not working with similar effects.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="personal_training_form" CssClass="pdfcalltoaction" runat="server" OnClick="personal_training_form_Click">Personal Training Form</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: You’d need to transmit the file on another page. If it’s a static file, you can always put the `download` attribute on the `<a>` element, which isn’t necessarily widely supported, but it will either download or be downloadable in a viewer otherwise, so…

Comment: It is a static file, but does it seems that IE/Firefox don't have the greatest support for download?

Comment: try to put onclick="return false;" in the <a> tag

Comment: @sine this did not work.

Comment: mhm ok, but if it is a static file why doesn´t you put the ~/programs/... in href attribute of the link, I think this should start a download

Comment: @sine It doesn't, browsers have built in pdf viewers (such as Chrome), I need the user to literally download the file, not view it inside of a browser.

Comment: Do you have to use the <a>?

Comment: @sine `onclick="return false;"` will actually make the link not hit the server at all. This is clearly not what the OP want.

Comment: You´re right, I thought maybe it will work because of the `OnServerClick="personal_training_form_Click"` attibute.

Comment: I had similar issues.  Check your server log and see if it reports any errors or exceptions.  (In my case, the error was "Cannot set content type after sending headers."

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void download_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding","Binary");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.pdf\"");
    Response.WriteFile(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + @"path\to\file\sample.pdf");
    Response.End();
}

<asp:LinkButton ID="download" runat="server" OnClick="download_Click">Download</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Messing with the content type shouldn't really be necessary. `application/pdf` works just fine.

Comment: @Lilluda5 Not my answer, also I was merely pointing out that setting the content type to something with no viewers should be unnecessary in any browser that supports `Content-Disposition`. Although you should still try the `application/octet-stream` hack which might work. (Even if it's "ugly".)